# AHK key combination issue

Tags: autohotkey, transliteration

Full code: http://pastebin.com/AX8iNRE6

Issue: I have various combinations of letters that work as a trigger to switch latin letters to cyrilic ones, for instance:

```
:*:h::
    SendInput, х
    FingerPrint(22)
    return
:*:s::
    SendInput, с
    FingerPrint(22)
    return

:*:sh::
    SendInput, ш
    FingerPrint(22)
    return
```

so it would switch 'sh' just to 'ш'. Instead, when I possibly don't type fast enough(or any other reason) it starts proceeding to substitute 's' and 'h' separately, giving me 'сх'

Is there any way I could go around this? maybe a condition that waits for next character or something.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: FingerPrint(22) might be useless here and totally unnecessary. I don't know what it is and what it's purpose. maybe from gui stuff that came with the original script before I edited to match keys I need. Original one had each key tied to only one letter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either try to build up something yourself using [Input](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Input.htm). Or, more comfortably, use Polythene's dynamic [regEx-Hotstring library](https://github.com/polyethene/AutoHotkey-Scripts/blob/master/Hotstrings.ahk):

```
#persistent
#include hotstrings.ahk

hotstrings("s([^h])", "c%$1%")    ; s followed by any non-h-character

return

:*:h::x
:*:sh::?
```